# Which API I need to use instead of serializeArray to get the custom attributes of fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using serializeArray() to retrive the form attributes. When I try to get the attributes, I'm receiving name and value for all the fields.

I have checked the documentation https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/. I understood it will return the name and value of all the fields.

Now I have few custom attributes for some fields. I want to retrieve them using those custom attributes.

How can i achieve this?

Here is my logic.

```
var data = $('form').serializeArray();
var newData = {};
var queue = {};
data.forEach(function(field) {
    if( field.customField != undefined && field.customField.indexOf("true")>=0 ) {
        queue[field.name] = frm.value
    } else {
        newData[frm.name] = frm.value;
    }

});
```

I need to get that customField attribute, I'm adding that to the HTML field attribute.

Answer (score 0):

May not be the best, but you can do like this.

Let's say you have set of text boxes, text areas and so on with custom data attributes in it. What I am doing here is adding a `class` to those fields that you need to get value / data attributes in it.

Let's take the following HTML as an example.

**HTML**

```
<form id="frm">
      <input class="serialize" type="text" name="title1" value="Test title 1" data-test1="test AAA" data-test2="test BBB" /><br/>
      <input class="serialize" type="text" name="title2" value="Test title 2" data-test1="test CCC" data-test2="test DDD" /><br/>
      <textarea class="serialize" data-test1="textarea test 1">TEST 22 TEST 11</textarea>
      <button id="btn" type="button">Serialize</button>
</form>
```

What I am doing here is iterating through fields which has class `.serialize` and putting value, name, data attributes and so on to an array.

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#btn').on('click', function(e) {  
            var dtarr = new Array();            
            $(".serialize").each(function(){
               var sub = new Array();
               sub['name'] = $(this).attr('name');
               sub['value'] = $(this).val();

               //data attribute example
               sub['data-test1'] = $(this).data('test1');
               sub['data-test2'] = $(this).data('test2');
               dtarr.push(sub); 
            });

            // This will give you the data array of input fields
            console.log(dtarr);
        });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes. we can do this, but when we serialize the form then the data of the fields will get duplicated right?

Comment: Hi @Pavan. Could you not use this instead of using `serializeArray()`?

Comment: Yes, we can use that. But if the form is the dynamic one, then the problem arises again.